# Launching wait pain screen when the JavaFX UI freezes

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a complex application, with a lot of graphic elements with complex `CSS` styles. When I open a file, a large number of nodes with complex styles are added to the scene, which leads to a significant interface freeze.

Problem example:

[image]

**Taking out loading data logic into a background thread does not solve problem, because the main part of the time is occupied by the process of adding graphical element with a large number of nodes and applying styles, which can only be performed in the UI thread.**

Currently I'm solving my problem using an alternative `Swing` graphics thread, forming a transparent `JDialog` above the `JavaFX` window. This solution is bad and unstable for a number of reasons. For example, with system screen scaling the `JavaFX` application is scaled, but `Swing` is not. And there are many other problems.

Alternative `Swing` solution code:

```
public static void runWithSwingWaitPane(Scene scene, Runnable runnable) {
    Bounds bounds = scene.getRoot().localToScreen(scene.getRoot().getBoundsInLocal());
    WaitApp.open(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
    runnable.run();
    Platform.runLater(WaitApp::close);
}

public class WaitApp {

    private static final JDialog dialog;

    static {
        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(WaitApp.class.getResource("/wait.gif")))));
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f));
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> dialog.setVisible(false));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void open(double x, double y, double v, double h) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            dialog.setLocation((int) x, (int) y);
            dialog.setSize((int) v, (int) h);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static void close() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(dialog::dispose);
    }
}
```

Alternative `Swing` solution example:

[image]

Alternative `Swing` solution problem after system screen scale change:

[image]

Below is an example of the code to get the problem.

```
public class Example extends Application {

    private List<StackPane> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<StackPane> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> styles = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(createScene());
        generateContent();
        stage.show();
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        StackPane content = new StackPane();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(content);
        VBox.setVgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);
        StackPane content1 = new StackPane();
        StackPane content2 = new StackPane();
        toolbar.getChildren().addAll(createButtons(root, content, content1, content2));
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(toolbar, content);
        list1.add(content1);
        list2.add(content2);
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/style.css");
        return scene;
    }

    private List<Button> createButtons(StackPane root, StackPane content, StackPane content1, StackPane content2) {
        Button first = new Button("first");
        Button second = new Button("second");
        first.setOnAction(event -> runWithWaitPain(root, () -> {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            content.getChildren().clear();
            content.getChildren().add(content1);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        }));
        second.setOnAction(event -> runWithWaitPain(root, () -> {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            content.getChildren().clear();
            content.getChildren().add(content2);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        }));
        return Arrays.asList(first, second);
    }

    private void runWithWaitPain(StackPane root, Runnable runnable) {
        Image image = new Image("/wait.gif");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            runnable.run();
            root.getChildren().remove(imageView);
        });
    }

    private void generateContent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            StackPane parent = list1.remove((int) (Math.random() * list1.size()));
            parent.getChildren().add(generateCell(list1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            StackPane parent = list2.remove((int) (Math.random() * list2.size()));
            parent.getChildren().add(generateCell(list2));
        }
    }

    private Node generateCell(List<StackPane> list) {
        StackPane pane1 = new StackPane();
        pane1.getStyleClass().add(styles.get((int) (Math.random() * 8)));
        list.add(pane1);
        StackPane pane2 = new StackPane();
        pane2.getStyleClass().add(styles.get((int) (Math.random() * 8)));
        list.add(pane2);

        Pane cell = Math.random() < 0.5 ? new HBox() : new VBox();
        cell.getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2);
        if (cell instanceof HBox) {
            HBox.setHgrow(pane1, Priority.ALWAYS);
            HBox.setHgrow(pane2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
        if (cell instanceof VBox) {
            VBox.setVgrow(pane1, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(pane2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

style.css

```
.aaa {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
.bbb {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.ccc {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
.ddd {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
.eee {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
.fff {
    -fx-background-color: orange;
}
.ggg {
    -fx-background-color: purple;
}
.hhh {
    -fx-background-color: gray;
}
```

In the current example, when adding an element with a large number of nodes, applying styles takes 20% of the total time, in a real project, applying styles takes 50% of the time.

Are there any other ways to display the waiting screen? Maybe there are some built-in or alternative solutions?

Running platform: Java version 8 (Liberica Full JDK 8u372+7)

Comment: *”the main part of the time is taken up by the process of applying styles”*. Are you certain of that? You say you are “loading” the styles. Where are you loading them from? Can you create an example where the long-running process really has to be executed on the FX Application Thread?

Comment: Unless your stylesheets are significantly more complicated than [modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), my guess is it's not the styling that's causing your freezes, at least not "directly". Perhaps you are simply adding too many nodes to the scene graph at once? But if you're confidant the CSS is the issue, have you considered styling the nodes in code instead? All CSS does is set various properties on the nodes (most of which can be set on a background thread if not "live").

Comment: I updated the question and made the example more close to the real case.

Comment: I would expect 10^5 layout nodes to scale poorly; why not a `Canvas`?

Comment: I think the solution is to figure out how to have less nodes being rendered at once. Maybe implement some kind of "virtualization" (e.g., what `ListView`, `TableView`, etc. all do with their cells). Or use a `Canvas` as trashgod mentioned, though I would make that a last resort if you need your users to interact with the UI.

Comment: As the comments show, this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Application with 10^5 nodes is just an example. In fact, I have a complex application with a complex structure where there are tabs inside which there are tabs. While application is running, everything works smoothly, because the content is added gradually. But during the system file opening, a lot of content is loaded at once and this effect occurs. Loading everything at once is a system solution to make working with the application smooth. If load content while switching tabs, small but unpleasant lags will be noticed. My only problem with loading is an adequate display of the loading screen